# Download an article with cURL given a dynamic download link

Tags: pdf, curl, download

I'm trying to download [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378426612000817) published journal article using `cURL`. It's the main page of an open access, so there should be not problems for anyone to see/download the article. I then extract the `pdfurl`, which keeps changing.

Then I try to download the pdf:

```
curl -L -o test.pdf "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378426612000817/pdfft?md5=6a85f34def09dd5cfb1d1b8feded0d51&pid=1-s2.0-S0378426612000817-main.pdf"
```

but all the time it redirects me to the main page, which is then downloaded as a html page called "test.pdf".

Comment: Have you tried using wget instead of curl?

Comment: It seems that this is a Science Direct download link, that is not working for some people. What is the page where you got the PDF URL from? Are you accessing from some organization or through some proxy service that gives you additional privileges at Science Direct?

Comment: I just tried this here... can you try with `curl -L --referer ";auto" -o test.pdf URL-for-direct-download`? It seems that the URL involves a redirect, and it also needs the referer header to be set correctly.

Comment: Why should that help?

Comment: wget supports retrieval through proxies, in my mind it is the better tool for the job

Comment: I don't use `wget` because I have to follow redirects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`curl` seems to handle redirects differently from `wget` by default. The direct download URL will involve some redirects and it also requires the HTTP referer header to be set correctly after the first redirect (otherwise, you will get a HTML page).

First, you need to enable location redirects in `curl` with `-L`, and then enable `curl`'s automatic handling of the referer header with `--referer ";auto"`, that is,

```
curl -L --referer ";auto" -o test.pdf URL-for-direct-download
```

Comment: I recommend [cliget](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/cliget/?src=cb-I) addon for `Firefox` that takes care of all of this automatically

Comment: Seems like a nice addon, @ArkadiuszDrabczyk. However, I would like to download the files given a list of DOIs from a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this fine

`wget -O main.pdf "http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0378426612000817/1-s2.0-S0378426612000817-main.pdf?_tid=5eb365f4-ea5e-11e4-b707-00000aacb360&acdnat=1429865356_af9bf791080efa05beb6e88a2c82b41b"`

Comment: Did you download a pdf? Because I get redirected to the [main page](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378426612000817).

Comment: Nope I definitely got a PDF. However when I tried it again I get a 404, the URL keeps changing.

`Saving to: ‘main.pdf’

main.pdf                           100%[==================================================================>] 391.42K  --.-KB/s   in 0.07s  

2015-04-24 10:01:20 (5.79 MB/s) - ‘main.pdf’ saved [400817/400817]

$ file main.pdf
main.pdf: PDF document, version 1.7`